# Choose the last rows of A and C to give eigenvalues 4,7 and 1,2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image: question]

I'm not able to solve it after, finding

$$ \det(A - \lambda I)  = \lambda^2(y)-x = 0 $$

Comment: Do you know how to construct a second-degree polynomial with $4$ and $7$ as solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 
$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
x&y
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
we have:

$$
\det (A-\lambda I)=
\det\begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda&1\\
x&y-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}
=\lambda(\lambda-y)-x=\lambda^2-y\lambda-x
$$

so we want that the equation $\lambda^2-y\lambda-x=0$ has solutions $\lambda_1=4$ and $\lambda_2=7$. This means that:
$$
\lambda^2-y\lambda-x=(\lambda-4)(\lambda-7)=\lambda^2-11\lambda+28
$$

So: $y=11$ and $x=-28$.

Can you do the same for the other matrix?

Comment: Shouldn't that be $y=11$ and $x=-28$?

Comment: I was confused by the same but anyways, thank you for the clear explanation. Spent almost 4 hours on google, not even a single solution :(

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Yes, thank you!  (stupid copy-past mistake):(

Comment: @Manikiran: Perhaps if you had spent those 4 hours thinking for yourself instead of trying to google up a ready-made solution ...